# SQL Update Select Statement Subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, subquery

I am stuck on an SQL Update Statement and was hoping for guidance on where I am going wrong.

This query below yields the following results.

```
SELECT a.ident, a.iata_code, m.nameAirport, m.codeIataAirport, m.codeIcaoAirport FROM airports a
INNER JOIN mytable m ON m.codeIataAirport = a.iata_code
where m.codeIcaoAirport IS NULL
```

results:

```
ident.   iata_code.  nameAirport. codeIataAirport.  codeIcaoAirport
OIAG.    AKW.        Aghajari.    AKW.              NULL
FMNE.    AMB.        Ambilobe.    AMB.              NULL
FTTU.    AMO.        Mao.         AMO.              NULL
```

I need to update mytable.codeIcaoAirport with the airports.ident column where the codeIcaoAirport field is NULL. In doing so I attempted this query which updated all of the codeIcaoAirports with the last records airports.ident. I have read through the statement a number of times and can't seem to find why it would do this

```
WITH subquery AS (
SELECT a.ident, m.nameAirport, m .codeIcaoAirport FROM airports a
INNER JOIN mytable m ON m.codeIataAirport = a.iata_code
where m.codeIcaoAirport IS NULL
)
UPDATE mytable
SET codeIcaoAirport = subquery.ident
FROM subquery;
```

How can I restructure this query to update mytable.codeIcaoAiport with the airports.ident values. The nexus between the tables is on the Inner join or m.codeIataAirport = a.iata_code

Comment: Check this out this code is for SQL Server. Removed the CTE and did a direct update.
`UPDATE m
SET m.codeIcaoAirport = a.ident
FROM airports a
INNER JOIN mytable m ON m.codeIataAirport = a.iata_code
WHERE m.codeIcaoAirport IS NULL;`

Comment: Comes back with a syntax error Execution finished with errors.
Result: near ".": syntax error
At line 1:
UPDATE m SET m.  

I am using DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: Modified the update statement to read UPDATE mytable SET codeIcaoAirport = a.ident FROM airports a INNER JOIN mytable m ON m.codeIcaoAirport = a.iata_code WHERE m.codeIcaoAirport IS NULL;

This again updated all of the codeIcaoAirport records with the last record in the  the following query. select a.ident FROM airports a INNER JOIN mytable m ON m.codeIataAirport = a.iata_code WHERE m.codeIcaoAirport IS NULL;

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Debug questions require a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is SQLite you can use this.

```
--  before the update
SELECT * FROM mytable;

-- Update "mytable" based on the "airports" table
UPDATE mytable
SET codeIcaoAirport = (SELECT ident FROM airports WHERE airports.iata_code = mytable.codeIataAirport)
WHERE codeIcaoAirport IS NULL;

--  after the update
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```